# Package for a comprehensive grade book?

Tags: tables, packages, package-writing

Good afternoon,

I'm wondering if there is some package for LaTeX that would enable one to enter and calculate grades, and additionally to create grade sheets to print.

If not, does anyone have any suggestions? How hard would it be to make this package myself? I imagine I would want to have a separate file to input all my information, such as assignments, scores, student names, etc. This would be similar to how bibliographies work, for example. Then I can insert it into the main.tex file which would run all the data, order it, and then display it in a beautiful way.

I'm using scim (a terminal-based spreadsheet program) to do this currently, however there are several drawbacks to this program, such as not being able to create different sheets in a single spreadsheet.

Thanks for you help and suggestions!

Comment: TeX is a programming language, so it's possible, but it will be hard.  It will come down to how much math you're wanting TeX to perform.  It would be easier to have scim do the math, and TeX just the displaying.  But if you're complaint is that your spreadsheet program can't have multiple sheets in one document, then it might be worthwhile to investigate other spreadsheet programs.

Answer (score 1):

It's theoretically possible to do this, but it would be kind of a pain and definitely not the best tool for the job. When I taught, I originally kept grades in a spreadsheet and was annoyed with the extra work involved. I ended up using a dedicated grade book application for the task and found it much more pleasant to work with since it could do things like print individual grade reports for each student. It's been a long time since I've taught so there's not much point in giving a specific recommendation.